# Redirection in zend framework 1.12 not working

Tags: zend-framework, redirect

i'm trying to redirect a page to the homepage of the site with some parameters changed. I'm using Zend 1.12 so i set up an action (setAction) inside the controller. The action changes a session variable and should redirect to the referring page. The following is the code of the action:

```
 public function setAction()
 {
    // if supported locale, add to session
     if (Zend_Validate::is($this->getRequest()->getParam('locale'), 'InArray',
        array('haystack' => array('en', 'it')))) 
    {
      $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('ttb.l10n');
      $session->locale = $this->getRequest()->getParam('locale');
    }
    // redirect to requesting URL
    $url = $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
    $this->redirect($url);
 }
```

This code is not throwing any exception but it is not doing what it is supposed to do, so it's not redirecting to the right page, it is only showing the phpinfo() page, without giving any more clue about what is happening.
Can anyone help?

UPDATE: The file the redirect is showing is the index.php file in the root directory of the server. When i remove it it doesn't show anymore the phpinfo() file but it says index.php not found. But i didn't tell it to render the index.php file. i just redirected it to the home page of the site. any other help is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the .htaccess file as it was set to read the index.php file, so i wrote:

```
 RewriteBase /project/public
```

It was:

```
 RewriteBase /
```

But i've noticed that it works even if i comment out the entire line.